# Reading previous URL in Backbone.history

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, web, window, browser-history

Can you read Backbone.history to see the previous URL the user was on within your app? If not, is there a way to extend Backbone routes to keep track?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get previous router/url in backbone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735111/get-previous-router-url-in-backbone-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default and with vanilla Backbone. It is definitely possible to extend the Router to keep a readable history. Take a look [here](http://c2journal.com/2013/02/04/backbone-router-nagivate-to-the-previous-route-using-backbone-simplerouter/).

The quick and dirty solution, however, is to use `document.referrer`, that *most of the time* will give you the previous URL the window was at.