# Get previous router/url in backbone application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a backbone application and i would require to know the router from which the current route is accessed. Is it possible?

For eg :-

I reach `#/current` from `#/test1` and also in another instance, from `#/test1`.

So can i know through some way to detect the previous router hit?

Ive used :

```
Backbone.history.fragment
```

and this only gives me the current route accessed and not from which route.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can store your history in some array and do some manipulation with last/previous items.

```
var history = [];
this.listenTo(this, 'route', function (name, args) {
  history.push({
    name : name,
    args : args,
    fragment : Backbone.history.fragment
  });
  console.log(history);
});
```

Comment: okay, i got this sometime back, but i was thinking of any built-in way with the backbone history or so to detect. I guess ill have to do it this way manually

Comment: ill leave this question open for 2-3 days more just to know whether there are any other ways through which someone else got this to work..Thanks @Vitaliy Petrychuk

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk I kind of like this approach but where am I supposed to run this snippet? In a View? In the Router? What do you suggest?

Comment: @darksoulsong, I would suggest to use Controller for this snippet. Backbone doesn't have it, but you can create it or if you use Marionette - it's already created for you. If you do not want to create a new Backbone.Controller you can run this snippet in the Router