# How to get previous hash url without $(window).on("hashchange", function (e) {});

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am using `backbone.js` to create a web application and I have a problem with `urls`. I want to get previous hash in `url` without using:

```
$(window).on("hashchange", function (e) {});
```

and store it in a variable.

Comment: Why do you care what the previous view was? It sounds like, whatever the problem is, you should be refactoring to be stateless.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get previous router/url in backbone application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18735111/get-previous-router-url-in-backbone-application)